# Current revision of entity in MySQL

Tags: mysql, query-performance

Suppose I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE `entities` (
   `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
      DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `data` VARCHAR(255),
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`timestamp`)
);
```

Each entity would normally only be referenced by `id`, except that there are multiple revisions for each entity, disambiguated by `timestamp`. The majority of my queries will be selecting the most recent revision, with only a small handful inserting new revisions, and even fewer selecting all past revisions. I expect only about a dozen revisions per `id` on average.

What is the most efficient (in terms of performance and storage space) method of selecting the most recent revision? Is there an accepted practice for this problem?

As I see it, there are two methods: (1) Create views around a `GROUP BY`

```
CREATE VIEW groupedEntities AS
   SELECT id, max(timestamp) AS maxt FROM entities GROUP BY id;
CREATE VIEW currentEntities AS
   SELECT a.id, data, timestamp FROM groupedEntities AS a
      INNER JOIN entities AS b ON b.id=a.id AND b.timestamp=a.maxt
      WHERE timestamp <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
SELECT * FROM currentEntities WHERE id=?;
```

Note the `<=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` allows 'deleting' an entity by setting a timestamp to the distant future. And (2) Create a separate table to store current revisions

```
CREATE TABLE currentEntities (
   `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
   `timestamp` TIMESTAMP,
   CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`id`, `timestamp`)
      REFERENCES `entities` (`id`,`timestamp`)
);
SELECT * FROM currentEntites INNER JOIN groupedEntities WHERE id=?;
```

Or some other option (3)?

Answer (score 0):

Views will eat your lunch in terms of performance, because of the way that MySQL handles views. Specifically, MySQL materializes an intermediate MyISAM table for a view, and does not "push" predicates from an outer query into a view (stored or inline).

The option of having a separate table that holds the frequently used "current" revisions would be the better option of the two you present. That does add complexity, keeping everything in sync, different queries to get current vs. historical, and the overhead of extra inserts, etc.

Given just the original table (storing all the historical revisions in the same table as the current revision (no separate table for just the most recent revision)...

A query with an inline view with a predicate INSIDE the view definition will give the best performance:

```
SELECT e.id
     , e.timestamp
     , e.data
  FROM `entities` e
  JOIN ( SELECT m.id 
              , MAX(m.timestamp) AS `timestamp`
           FROM `entities` m
          WHERE m.id = ?
          GROUP BY m.id
       ) c
     ON c.id = e.id 
    AND c.timestamp = e.timestamp
```

The EXPLAIN output should show "`Using where; Using index`" on the step to materialize the inline view (derived table). The join predicate on the outer query is by primary key, which is optimal for the retrieval of the `data` column.

Comment: The reason I wanted to use views in the first place was that I have three different tables, each with this sort of versioning, and I need to join over all of the current entries. Without views, the select statement looks horrendous, but I see the value of putting the predicate inside the inner select.

Comment: Related question, in the single-table case, how can I enforce foreign key constraints from another table? The primary key isn't just `id` but also includes `timestamp`, but I want to reference `id` as a key, only there is no table where `id` is a unique column.